# json_encode() in php is not working with SQL Query UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, json

server

```
<?php
.
.
**$sql = "UPDATE user_login SET userid = '".$userid."', active = 1  WHERE 
useruuid ='".$useruuid."';"; 
     $query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
     $success = mysql_fetch_row($query);**

        $response = array("test"=>"test");

        echo json_encode($response);  

        mysql_close($connect);

        return;
     >
```

client (ios)

```
        NSData * data  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
options:0 error:&jsonParseError];
        NSString * test =[dict objectForKey:@"test"];
```

in ios dict is nil when UPDATE query is working in php.
but dict has data when UPDATE query is not working in php.
why?

how I use UPDATE query with json_encode() in php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$response=array();
$sql = "UPDATE user_login SET userid = '".$userid."', active = 1  WHERE useruuid ='".$useruuid."';"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
$success = mysql_fetch_row($query);
//$response = array("test"=>"test");
$response['test']="test";
mysql_close($connect);
echo json_encode($response);  
die();
?>
```